# Merge columns within dataframe based on column value R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I currently have a data frame of this structure

```
    ID-No  cigsaday   activity  
    1      NA        1           
    2      NA        1          
    1       5       NA          
    2       5       NA
```

I want to concatenate the rows with the identical ID numbers and create a new data frame that is supposed to look like this

```
ID-No  cigsaday   activity  
    1      5        1           
    2      5        1
```

The data frame includes characters as well as numerical, in this way we would match based on a participant ID which occurs 4 times in the dataset within the first column.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution using na.locf() which replaces a value with the most recent non-NA value.

```
library(zoo)

dat %>% 
  group_by(IDNo) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()),.funs=function(x) na.locf(x)) %>% 
  distinct(IDNo,cigsaday,activity,.keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), ID_No]
   ID_No cigsaday activity
1:     1        5        1
2:     2        5        1
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID_No = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), cigsaday = c(NA, NA,
5L, 5L), activity = c(1L, 1L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways lead to Rome. For the sake of completeness, here are some other approaches which return the expected result for the given sample dataset. Your mileage may vary.

#### 1. dplyr, na.omit()

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID_No) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), na.omit))
```

> ```
> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>   ID_No cigsaday activity
>   <int>    <int>    <int>
> 1     1        5        1
> 2     2        5        1
> ```

Note, this a `dplyr` version of [ThomasIsCoding's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66556070/3817004).

#### 2. dplyr, reduce(), coalesce()

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID_No) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ purrr::reduce(.x, coalesce)))
```

#### 3. data.table, fcoalesce()

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) fcoalesce(as.list(x))), ID_No]
```

> ```
>    ID_No cigsaday activity
> 1:     1        5        1
> 2:     2        5        1
> ```

#### 4. data.table, Reduce(), fcoalesce()

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, Reduce, f = fcoalesce), ID_No]
```